# Why do I get a NaN when computing the KL divergence between two OneHotCategorical distributions?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I try to calculate the KL-Divergence between two OneHotCategorical distributions with the following code:

```
posterior = tfd.OneHotCategorical(probs=[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
prior     = tfd.OneHotCategorical(probs=[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

and the result:

```
print(posterior.kl_divergence(prior))
tf.Tensor(nan, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Is this a bug or is the result wanted? I tested it a little bit and the error refers to the calculation of the KL-divergence, where a problem with 0. values occurs (logarithm and division). In this case, the KL-divergence should get set to 0.0 in my opinion.
Regards
Tensorflow version: 2.1.0-rc1
Tensorflow probability version: 0.8.0

Comment: This is probably due to computing `log(0)`. So if you need a fix, just add a small epsilon whenever it's zero.

Comment: Yes, that was my workaround too. Anyway, it is a bug and should get fixed, because the impossible event (probability = 0.) should get considered in probability distributions also.

Answer (score 0):

Can you report it on http://github.com/tensorflow/probability ? We track issues there.